# c++ won't recognise socket.h as a valid header

Tags: c++, macos

I was trying to compile c++ code on a mac running OS X 10.10.2 with the developer tools installed which included the following header

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
```

but I get the following error

```
client.cpp:1:24: fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
#include <sys/socket.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

I tried reinstalling c++ compiler from the developer tools and also from the method shown here

https://wiki.helsinki.fi/display/HUGG/Installing+the+GNU+compilers+on+Mac+OS+X

I also checked $PATH on my bash terminal and it is set correctly. Please help me in getting the code to compile on my mac

P.S. - it compiles on my friends laptop who is running linux

P.P.S. - outputs that might help

g++ -v outputs

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Configured with: ../gcc-4.9-20141029/configure --enable-languages=c++,fortran
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 20141029 (prerelease) (GCC)
```

and clang++ -v outputs

```
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

xcode-select -p outputs

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

xcode-select --install outputs

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

Comment: $PATH doesn't matter at all; it's only used for finding executables.

Comment: Unless you have a good reason, you shouldn't be running gcc on OS X 10.10. You should be running clang.

Comment: What is the output of `xcode-select -p` and `xcode-select --install`?

Comment: Also, what is the output of `whereis g++` and `whereis c++` and `whereis clang++`

Comment: @Bill There are tons of good reasons. Clang still has some trouble with variadic templates, for instance, and thus cannot be used in conjunction with [R Martinho’s remastered `enable_if`](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/06/01/almost-static-if.html).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I completely agree. It was just that if you don't have any reason, then you should probably use the vendor recommended toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your compiler installation.
What is `g++ -v` and `clang++ -v`output?
Try to install native command line tools for Xcode from 
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?=command%20line%20tools or g++ using, for example, homebrew package manager http://brew.sh